# Server Specific Settings for jQuery AJAX/GET requests? (Error 500)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have just uploaded a website to a brand new server, and am consistently getting Error 500s from the server when I try to do an AJAX/GET request. It appears to be loading the actual file, but then something is going wrong - and no error reporting tells me anything other than its a 500! I searched about 10-15 threads on here, all of which said "its a server problem", but then went on to suggest changes to their code to make it better.

An example of the code which ends up returning a 500 is:

```
$(function() {
             $("#student_search").autocomplete({
                  source: "functions/find_student.php",
                  delay: 100,
                  minLength: 3,
                  select: function( event, ui ) {
                      highlightStudent(ui.item.value, ui.item.id.id, ui.item.id.house);
                  }
            }); 
         });
```

Which is the jquery ui autocomplete widget, which also returns a 500 error.

My questions is, could there be something on the server that is not set and is causing these 500 errors? Im annoyed by the lack of information being provided by the web browser (firebug and chrome both give me the same information :().

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: Most likely there is a problem in the `functions/find_student.php`. Updating the question with the code will be helpful

Comment: Hi there thanks. Yeah, checking the code of the things being called has been a part of my last few hours - and it could definitely be an issue there but I cant trace it. Things dont include, echos work sometimes, session variables can be called but database calls seem to trigger the 500s, includes do, object calls etc. The find student code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/y4opg2wd/

Comment: replace json.encode with json_encode. Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy :(